# Not able to access samba share in Nautilus on Unbutu 22.04

Tags: mount, 22.04, nautilus, samba

I am running OpenMediaVault NAS version 6 on a Raspberry Pi and have a SMB/CIFS share that I can access from Nautilus on a Ubuntu 20.04 install and also on Android, but does not work in Nautilus on a Ubuntu 22.04 install.
When in Nautilus, I go to "+ Other locations" I see the SMB/CIFS file share, and when I click on it, it prompts me for my credentials but after entering a clicking "Connect", I get the following error message:

> Unable to access location
> Failed to retrieve share list from server: invalid argument

When I add `server min protocol = nt1` in the setting on the server, it works on Nautilus Ubuntu 22.04 as well, but as far as I understand, that protocol is insecure and slow. I would rather make Nautilus work properly instead of making changes on my server. Any ideas on how to fix Nautilus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fix nautilus. The developers have to fix nautilus.

My advice is to bypass the way Nautilus connects to the share. You can do this two different ways:

***[1] Ask for the server and it's share explicitly in Nautilus. So in Connect to Server it would be of the form:***

```
smb://server/share-name
```

Where "server" can be:

The ip address of the server.

The mdns host name of the server which is the host name with a **.local** attached at the end.

*Note: this requires the server to have avahi-daemon installed and running.*

You can try the host name by itself but that may prove problematic.

Once it connects you can bookmark it so you don't have to do this again.

***[2] You can also do a mount.cifs mount. Something like:***

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mountpoint -o guest,uid=1000
```

Or if it requires authentication:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mountpoint -o username=XXXX,password=YYYY,uid=1000
```

You can set this up in fstab do you don't have to do a manual mount all the time. I can detail how to do that if option [1] isn't enough.

Either way does not require the server to have NT1 enabled. It will connect using SMB3 if your server is up to date.

Comment: Thank you Morbius1! That worked and is exactly what I needed. I am using option 1.